# Tkinter entry box and math related programming

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a program using tkinter to convert seconds to a h:m:s format. I got my tkinter gui mostly done. I'm just stuck on a math programming related issue and potentially a tkinter GUI issue.

When I was testing and trying to print the h:m:s result to the shell, I got

Comment: You have a comma in the wrong place in the statement that is causing the error.

Comment: @BryanOakley which part is the comma in the wrong place at?

Comment: Just a note: you can always use `time.strftime()` to get the time in a specific format - such as `time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())` in your case to get the time in h:m:s.

Answer (score 1):

The bracket

```
m,s = divmod(int(self.secondsEntry.get(),60))
                                           ^
                                           |
```

should be here instead:

```
m,s = divmod(int(self.secondsEntry.get()),60)
                                        ^
                                        |
```

This first one means "convert this base-60 string to int", and Python doesn't have symbols for bases > 36 (0-9 + a-z). If you don't specify a base it defaults to base-10.

**Edit:**

There are two basic solutions to your overwriting problem.

The simplest option is to delete the Entry content before writing a new value,

```
    self.result.delete(0, END)
    self.result.insert(0,c)
```

The more complex (but powerful) option is to bind your Entry box to a StringVariable,

```
    self.resultVar = StringVar()
    self.result = Entry(master = self.root_window, textvariable = self.resultVar)
```

then you can write to it like

```
    self.resultVar.set(c)     # automatically updates the Entry value
```

Comment: I have another question. I edited my code to reflect it, but this is regarding the tkinker display. When I press calculate, the first result runs perfectly, but after that, it just appends to the last result. How would I fix it?